# angular 2 | @ContentChildren not populated, directive in component

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components

I'm trying to get nested directives from a parent directive with `@ContentChildren`, but not being populated, occurs when parent directive is placed over a component, component template has child directives.

---

**example 1 (@ContentChildren not populated)**:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Zdxp017V3zwNYTOR11dR?p=preview

**example 2, works fine**:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ryIomfokiO40Sw8X6Axd?p=preview

there any way to make it work example 1? or wait for "some-component" content?

thanks in advance

Comment: `ContentChildren` works only for the component-owner of template.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/qEv9pOPgtdVvB5e9yehf?p=preview