# ContentChildren Not Populating Angular 5

Tags: angular

I have a `Panes` component which can contain multiple `Pane`s. I have to be able to access the individual `Pane`s inside of the `Panes` component. To do that I am using `ContentChildren` but for some reason it doesn't recognize/register the `Pane`s even though they are being rendered.

Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Panes

```
@Component({
  selector: "panes",
  template: `
    <ng-content select="[pane]"></ng-content>
  `
})
export class Panes {
  @ContentChildren(Pane) panes: QueryList<Pane>;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log("Initial: ", this.panes.length);
    this.panes.changes.subscribe(changes => {
      console.log("After Changes: ", changes.length);
    });
  }
}
```

Pane

```
 @Directive({selector: 'pane'})
    export class Pane {
      @Input() id: string;
    }
```

Markup

```
<panes>
  <div pane>
    1
  </div>
  <div pane>
    2
  </div>
  <div pane *ngIf="show">
    3
  </div>
</panes>
<button type="button" (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button>
```

Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/rTVsFoPFu7uBOpweWXW4?p=preview

Comment: According to the comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39924148/angular-2-contentchildren-not-populated-directive-in-component), ContentChildren only works for components. I have no idea if that's true, but certainly your example works if you flip Pane to be a component.

Comment: I dont think thats true. I tried that though: https://plnkr.co/edit/HOQ0fUd38rCsm3WNSEPo?p=preview Still doesnt work

Comment: [You didn't update your HTML](https://plnkr.co/edit/MFPhn55WHAloRXnjedBq?p=preview)

Comment: Thats right. Thanks everyone! If one of you could post this as an answer, I would like to accept it and upvote your answer

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas ContentChildren certainly works for directives, as also example in docs uses directives https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren

Answer (score -1):

I have landed here as I am facing similar problem, but I found out that your problem is just about wrong selector in Pane directive.

It should be:

```
@Directive({selector: '[pane]'})
export class Pane
```

instead of:

```
@Directive({selector: 'pane'})
export class Pane
```

brackets [] are missing there

here is stackblitz of your working example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow48159514?embed=1&file=src/app/pane.directive.ts